# Node.js server working fine on local but not on server

Tags: node.js, express, amazon-ec2

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.listen(3000, function () {
console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
});

app.get('/getCode', function (req, res) {

res.send("hai");
})
```

the server starts successfully,but on calling the ip:3000/getCode doesn't give a response.

I have opened the port 3000,and am on aws ec2 ubuntu server

[image: inbound rules in aws]

Comment: ping the IP? whether its reachable?

Comment: did `curl 127.0.0.1:3000/getCode` inside the shell work?

Comment: First thing to check is if you can connect form the server itself. Install links or elinks console web browser (it's available from the aws repo so apt-get or yum depending on your OS). Then using links or elinks try to browse your server from aws itself. If this works then something between your aws instance and your PC is blocking port 3000. Check both aws security settings and your local firewalls (check both the one on your PC if any and your router)

Comment: ... or do as Sridhar suggested and use curl :D

Comment: yes it works inside the server `curl 127.0.0.1:3000/getCode` gives me response

Comment: can you access the public ip of your aws instance ?

Comment: yes, i can access it. I install apache to test , and when i call the public ip it gives the apache page

Comment: now try to access public_ip:3000/getCode

Comment: its doesn't give any response

Comment: can you post output of following command  sudo netstat -tupln | grep 3000 update your answer.

Comment: `tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3000            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN   `   `1281/nodejs`

Comment: Are you sure that your instance is in the security-group that you edited?

Answer (score 0):

change source from custom ip to anywhere and 0.0.0.0. this will allow you to access that api from any IP address once you are sure this works you can change it to custom ip address to the ip address you want to access from.

Answer (score 0):

try setting port like this:

```
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.listen(port, function () {
 console.log('Example app listening on port:' + port);
});
```

**Explanation:** When hosting your application on another service (like Heroku, Nodejitsu, and AWS), your host may at times independently configure the `process.env.PORT` variable for you.

Comment: that cannot be the case here as in ec2 you have complete control over your server and your application start on the port you mention in your application

Comment: might be, but it is the case in AWS Elastic Beanstalk. Besides it is a safer way to define a port rather than hard code it. As in later run one can change the port simply by changing the environment variable  ```$ export PORT=4000```

Comment: yes but that is not the problem that he is facing ,anyways it looks like he has made some mistake with firewall.